# how to loop through an entire datagrid in f1 and pass values as string to label in f2

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

i have a datagrid in say form1 with some records in it and form 2 as a registration form which shows as dialog to form1. now upon a new registration with form2 i need to check whether the client has already been registered or not with records in the datagrid and display a message saying client already exist. so far i've been successful in passing a selected row in form1 as string to compare what ever client name being entered in form2. now i would like to know how to loop through entire datagrid and pass them as values to a label in form2 to enhance my checking up. below is how i do passing from form1 to form2

form 1 string declaration

```
 public string strlabel2
    {

        get { return txtboxClearingAgent.Text; }

    }
```

this where txtboxClearingAgent is taken from

```
  private void kryptonDataGridView1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtboxClearingAgent.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Clearing Agent Name"].Value.ToString();
```

and passed to form2 through showdialog

```
  private void kryptonButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmNewClient frmNewClient1 = new frmNewClient();
        frmNewClient1._strData = strlabel2;
            frmNewClient1.ShowDialog();
```

and received in form 2

```
    public string _strData
    {

        set { lblDatagrid.Text = value; }

    }
```

and if statement to check during insertion

```
    if (lblDatagrid.Text == txtboxClientName.Text)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Client exist", "Checking Client(s) List", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        return;
                    }

                    else if (lblDatagrid.Text != txtboxClientName.Text)
                    {

                        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save this Entry?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("New Client Entry has successfully been Saved", "Saving Client(s) Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }


                        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                             return;
                        }

                        int result1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        lblDat.Text = "1";

                    }
```

Comment: That's a "messy" solution, do you have the records in the grid saved in a database and how do you save/retrieve them?

Comment: You should have viewmodels for your views. Do all the Business logic in your viewmodels. (This is MVVM, google it)

Comment: yes they r in  mysql database and i retrieve them with a stored procedure

Comment: @DrKoch is mvvm supported in winform, because i know it be targetted at wpf and silverlight

Comment: MVVM is a design concept, independent of an implementation (although it is simpler in WPF)